# Set of laptop models that support battery health management

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, battery

I have updated my **MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)** to the latest Mac Os Catalina **10.15.5 (19F96)** which should include [battery health management feature](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/HT211094).

But I can't find it in my settings. 
[image]

I assume that there must be a list of supported devices, but I couldn't find them.